# Get value out of static rails select_tag

Tags: ruby, web

I have just started out programming with ruby on rails. I really like it, but sometimes it's really complicated. What I am trying to do is to get the selected value out of the select_tag and pass it to the Model where I will multiply the value to another one (that comes from an from_for textfield).
The problem is I wasn't able to figure out how to get the value from the View to the Controller and then to the Model.

Here is my code:

View:

```
<%= label_tag 'Remind' %>
<%= f.number_field :remind %>
<%= select_tag :select_conv, options_for_select([['Day', 1], ['Week', 7], ['Month', 30]]) %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
  add = Item.new(item_params)

  if add.save
    flash[:notice] = ''
    redirect_to items_path
  else
    redirect_to new_item_path
    flash[:error] = ''
  end

private
def item_params
params.require(:item).permit(:itemname, :amount, :bbf, :remind)
end
end
```

Model:

```
def convert_to_d
  convert = self.remind * self.v_convertor
  self.assign_attributes(remind: convert)
end
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you receiving data in the variable item_params?

Comment: Yes. This is the code (sorry for non adding): private
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:itemname, :amount, :bbf, :remind)
end

Comment: Could you add this code to your question? Just click in edit button and update it. Here in SO it's important to format your questions. Also, this code is important to answer your question.

Comment: Of course...sorry is my first question on the forum so I'm not verry used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some changes:

View:

```
<%= label_tag 'Remind' %>
<%= f.number_field :remind %>
<%= select_tag :select_conv, options_for_select([['Day', 1], ['Week', 7], ['Month', 30]]) %>
```

From the View, it will return a hash with the values of each user's input. So, for this example, it will return:

```
params = { remind: user_input, select_conv: user_input }
```

You can catch that in your controller with the method item_params, but
you have to specify the parameters that you want in your method, so your item_params should be:

Controller:

```
def create
  add = Item.new(item_params)

  if add.save
    flash[:notice] = ''
    redirect_to items_path
  else
    redirect_to new_item_path
    flash[:error] = ''
  end
end

private 
def item_params 
  params.require(:item).permit(:itemname, :amount, :bbf, :remind, :select_conv) # << update here 
end
```

In your model, you can access the values saved in item_params with their names, as you did with *self.remind*, you can call it with *self.select_conv*.

Model:

```
# self.select_conv can be used now.

def convert_to_d
  convert = self.remind * self.v_convertor
  self.assign_attributes(remind: convert)
end
```

You can also use some validations in your model to guarantee integrity from the user's data. For more information about [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I get an error when I change the code that way: undefined method `select_conv' for #<Item:0x007f3428a22570>. But I see that the params are passed.

Comment: I need more information to be able to help you. Could you update your question with the Hash that comes from the view. And also, did you create select_conv attrib in your Item's table? Otherwise, Item will not know what select_conv is - Add your Item table information in your question too, you can find it in db/schema.rb. To add this information, edit your question and put it there.

Comment: Ok this way it would work. But I don't really want to save it on my database. This is the reason why I didn't created it when I generated the Model. Is it not possible to do this without saving the data on the DB?

Comment: Update your table Item to add the attribute select_conv. Then, in your model you can add a validation to not save this attribute. I think that is the best way. Creating a migration is simple as not save the variable in the db.

Comment: Just update your table Item to add this variable, and in your model you make a validation to not save this var. Very easy, two commands.

Comment: Glad that I could help!